# Calling a module function whenever a user makes a change to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: This current code returns a compile error "argument not optional .

I am trying to call a function from a module within a spreadsheet. Anytime a user makes a change -> `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` The code under that user change sub looks like:

Add policy code

```
        If CurCol(PolicyCode) Then
        'Policy Code
        Set PolicyCode = Call PolicyCodeFromOtherModuleHere
```

The function I am trying to use to calculate the cells value is from another module and looks like:

```
Function PolicyCode(gm As Double, Optional previous As String)

If gm > 1 Then
    gm = gm * 0.01
End If

    gm = Round(gm, 3)

    If previous = "E" Or previous = "O" Then
        PolicyCode = previous
    ElseIf previous Like "1?" Then
        If gm < 0.03 Then
            PolicyCode = "1B"
        ElseIf gm < 0.05 Then
            PolicyCode = "1C"
        ElseIf gm < 0.08 Then
            PolicyCode = "1D"
        ElseIf gm < 0.12 Then
            PolicyCode = "1E"
        ElseIf gm < 0.16 Then
            PolicyCode = "1F"
        ElseIf gm < 0.24 Then
            PolicyCode = "1G"
        ElseIf gm < 0.29 Then
            PolicyCode = "1H"
        ElseIf gm < 0.47 Then
            PolicyCode = "1J"
        Else: PolicyCode = "1K"
        End If
    ElseIf previous = "8" Or previous = "P" Or previous = "V" Or previous = "4" Or previous = "R" Then
        If gm < 0.35 Then
            PolicyCode = "8"
        ElseIf gm < 0.45 Then
            PolicyCode = "P"
        ElseIf gm < 0.58 Then
            PolicyCode = "V"
        ElseIf gm < 0.7 Then
            PolicyCode = "4"
        Else: PolicyCode = "R"
        End If
    Else
        If gm < 0.16 Then
            PolicyCode = "Y"
        ElseIf gm < 0.24 Then
            PolicyCode = "Z"
        ElseIf gm < 0.29 Then
            PolicyCode = "X"
        ElseIf gm < 0.36 Then
            PolicyCode = "9"
        ElseIf gm < 0.41 Then
            PolicyCode = "J"
        ElseIf gm < 0.47 Then
            PolicyCode = "N"
        ElseIf gm < 0.55 Then
            PolicyCode = "D"
        ElseIf gm < 0.63 Then
            PolicyCode = "S"
        ElseIf gm < 0.75 Then
            PolicyCode = "T"
        Else: PolicyCode = "U"
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

the goal is to get that function to calculate what policy code should be put into the policy code column based off of whatever percentage is in the gm (gross margin) column. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Does the code not do it? I see you're assigning a policy code...?  You just do, say, `Range("A1").Value = PolicyCode`, no?  Or maybe `Cells(1, Target.Column).Value = PolicyCode`?

Comment: I keep getting a compile error : "Argument not optional" and it highlights (PolicyCode) right before CurCol

Comment: Depends where you want the policy code, but this is very doable.  You can pass the target to your function from the selection change (I see that you do not), so you can change the target cell (modified cell) or a cell that is offset to the target (say next one to the right or anywhere on the sheet really).

Comment: If your question is about an error, then it should describe what that error is, say what line/instruction is causing it, and include a [mcve]. But your question doesn't appear to be about a specific error. I don't know what your question is asking. If you just want help finishing your code, see [*why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513).

Comment: Sorry, edited to reflect error. - How should i code that @Wookies-Will-Code

Comment: Where is the error? That very first line? What's `CurCol`?

Comment: The first line of the If statement If CurCol(PolicyCode) Then set ...

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options, handle the location placement in your module / sub or handle it on the spot in your selection sub you are working in.

Here is an example of handling it in your selection code. In this case I am handling a calendar pop up in a specific cell on a worksheet set up as a "form".
When the workbook opens this cell is loaded with today's date through = VBA.Date.  In this way there is always a seed for the function either today's date or whatever date was last selected on the calendar.  There is optional code to always bring the calendar up in focus on today's date to start with, but that is not important to what you are looking for.  This is the backstory for the small piece of code to make any sense to you.  I have a bunch of these selection codes on this "form".

Variables in this code:

```
Dim msrSheet As Worksheet
Dim calendarLoc As Range

Set msrSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Generate MSR")
Set calendarLoc = msrSheet.Range("E9")

   'Handle the Selection of the Calendar Cell
    If Not Intersect(Target, calendarLoc) Is Nothing Then
        'Check for a single cell selection
        If Target.Count = 1 Then
            'Handle it right here on the spot
            Target = CalendarForm.GetDate(Target.value)
        Else
            MsgBox "Please only select one cell within the range.  You have selected: " & Target.Count & " cells.", , "Choose only one cell"
        End If
    Else ' Do nothing
    End If
```

To pass to a sub it is the same as the code for the selection change pretty much:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
```

Depends, I typically use modules and private subs.

```
Private Sub mySub (ByVal myTarget as Range)
    'Perform code, you have the original Target passed in now as myTarget for the scope of this sub, you could name it the same if you want
End Sub
```

To call those from elsewhere in the modules or WS or WB code:

```
Application.Run "ModuleNameHere.SubNameHere", Arg1, Arg2 
'Say you pass Target to mySub, you have a module myModule with a private sub mySub in it
Application.Run "myModule.mySub", Target
```

Make sense?

---

Here is a comment / answer from Sid on another thread:

Yup :-) By the way do you know that for multiple sheets you can use

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
         'Selection code or handlers
    End Sub
```

'in lieu of

```
Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

You have to then place the code in thisworkbook and you can get away by create a sub in a module ;) – Siddharth Rout Sep 23 '16 at 15:21